# Execute function every 10 minutes with final 5

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to execute a function in angularjs every 10 minutes with final minute 5, for example:
Function will execute once [...] 11:05, 11:15, 11:25, 11:35, 11:45, 11:55 [...]

I know I can set an interval like this, but I can't apply together:

```
function getStuff() {
   $http.get().success(function(data) {
       $timeout(getStuff, 5000);
   });
});
```

Comment: I think the best way I can think of would be to have two timers one is started in the beginning and it updates each second looking for the first date ending in XX:X5 once found - it starts the other timer, which simply waits 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to set an initial $interval to check for the time and check if the minute ends with a 5. Once it does, then you can run your $interval to run the job every 10 mins.

```
// run every min to check if time ends in 5
var stopTimeCheck = $interval(function() {
   var currMin = new Date().getMinutes();
    // check if minute time ends in 5
   if (currMin % 5 === 0 && currMin % 10 !== 0) {
       $interval(function() {
          $http.get().then(...);
       }, 600*1000); // run every 10 mins
       $interval.cancel(stopTimeCheck);
   }
}, 60*1000)
```

Comment: but... for example.. if access the page (or refresh) at 11:07, it will never execute, right?

Comment: oh no, will execute every minute, I saw only now

Answer (score 2):

use `$interval` to call the function every 10 minutes.

```
function getStuff() {
   $http.get().success(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
   });
});

$interval(getStuff,600000)
```

Comment: I know, but the problem, as I said, is start and continue executing every 10 minutes in hour that finish with minute 5, like 11:05, 11:15....

Comment: and I guess that 10 minutes in miliseconds is 600000